# Route Print shows Interface as "c"

Tags: networking, routing, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

We are having issues with servers that are losing their network access after reboot.  When I was looking at route print, I noticed under the Interface it says C.  Any idea what this is?

Currently in order to get network access back is to disable and re-enable the NIC, and the proper routes are put back in place.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...00 1d d8 b7 1c 92 ......Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.9.46.253                c    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link                 c    261
   169.254.70.226  255.255.255.255         On-link                 c    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link                 c    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link                 c    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link                 c    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.9.46.253  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    261 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    261 fe80::a1cb:4bab:ebf4:46e2/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Do they have static IP addresses? It looks like they are set to pick up IP addresses from DHCP and are not reaching a DHCP server, so they are using APIPA addresses instead.

Comment: No this server has a static IP address, DHCP not involved at all here.

Comment: I wonder how it picked up APIPA addresses, then?

Comment: Please post output from ipconfig /all